# Print multiple jobs without interruption c#

Tags: c#-4.0, printing, printdocument

Is there a way to print multiple jobs in a row, without letting **another** user send a print job in between? (sort of "don't give the token to another user as long as my print **jobs** haven't finished")

It's a shared printer and many users have access to it, and what I'm printig is a big document so it takes some time;
I'm using more then one job because its pages are not to be printed from the same paper tray, so I have to switch the paper source in my code.

Help please! and thanks in advance.

***P.S.*** *I'm using the PrintDocument object of .Net*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't, as far are I know, you'd need to either keep the printer busy by keeping the job open and sending PJL or other commands that don't eject a page.  The other option is to concatenate your jobs together into one large job.  I guess you could also programatically pause the shared print queue and send the data directly using a direct IP print port or something.  In the end there isn't an elegant solution to this.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but is it possible to concatenate jobs with different **PageSettings** and **PrinterSettings**?

Comment: Yes, one 'file' could be the concatenation of 10 different postscript and/or PCL etc. print jobs. As each job has a start and end, often containing a printer reset, the device will handle it as though it received them as separate jobs. The key is to ensure these resets are there especially if you are switching languages between PCL and Postscript (for example).  I recommend putting some PJL in between each job.

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of using multiple jobs, I can just change the settings for each page when printing (modify the PrintPageEventHandler), [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/261978-possible-combine-two-printdocuments)'s a link, and a sample of my code:

   ```
   private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
   {
       using (Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(streamList[currentPageIndex]))
       {
           // If it's the first page
           if (currentPageIndex == 0)
           {
               // Use a certain tray
               ev.PageSettings.PaperSource = PaperTrayPage1;
           }
           // For the rest of the document
           else
           {
               // Use another tray
               ev.PageSettings.PaperSource = PaperTrayRest;
           }

           currentPageIndex++;

           ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, ev.PageBounds);
           ev.HasMorePages = (currentPageIndex < streamList.Count);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Combining multiple jobs (PrintDocument objects) is possible, [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/combine-multiple-printdocuments/)'s an example.